# Uber API maps url not loading in android webview

Tags: android, google-maps, android-webview, uber-api

I have integrated Uber API in my code. The `GET /v1/requests/{request_id}/map` gives me link `https://trip-dc2.uber.com/4wxDJ2qUs6` I have tried all the methods to load it in a webview all it shows is a blank page.

---

```
 new LoadSocialNetworkUrlTask().execute("https://trip-dc2.uber.com/4wxDJ2qUs6");

 public class LoadSocialNetworkUrlTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(UberMapViewActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading,Please wait...");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.show();
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(final String... url) {
        try {


            ((WebView) shareRideWebView).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

            ((WebView) shareRideWebView).setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                @Override
                public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view,
                                               SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                    handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    // TODO hide your progress image
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            ((WebView) shareRideWebView).getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            ((WebView) shareRideWebView).loadUrl(url[0]);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... url) {
        try {
            publishProgress(url);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

---

It works in a standalone application but in my actual application this page is not loading. I have given Internet permission also in the manifest.

Comment: Do you have any logs/errors you could share with us?

Comment: No there are no error which i see in the logs.

Answer (score 3):

The way you're loading the webview in onProgressUpdate is weird.

This works with the URL provided on the main thread.

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("https://trip-dc2.uber.com/4wxDJ2qUs6");
```

Configure your webview and webclient up front in the main thread. Call load synchronously from the main thread. start your dialog loading and then dismiss when you get the result from the client.